# No PHP, existe alguma maneira de importar apenas uma função de um determinado arquivo?

Tags: php, funções

Eu vejo que, no Python, podemos importar apenas uma função de um determinado módulo, sem ter que carregar ele todo. Além de isso ser ótimo para evitar conflitos de nomes de funções.

Exemplo:

```
#funcs.py

def x(x):
    return 'x'

def y(y):
    return 'y'


#main.py

from funcs import y

print(y()); #y
print(x()); #erro é gerado
```

Porém, no PHP, quando temos o mesmo cenário, temos:

```
#func.php

function x($x)
{
    return 'x';
}

function y($y)
{
     return 'y';
}

#main.php

include_once 'funcs.php';

echo y(); // y
echo x(); // x
```

Mesmo sabendo que não há meios nativos de se importar apenas uma função, em PHP, existe alguma solução para isso?

Ou realmente, sempre devo usar o padrão abaixo quando vou utilizar funções em php?

```
if (! function_exists('y')) {

     function y($y){ return 'y'; }
}
```

Comment: Estou perguntando isso porque não me parece uma boa idéia separar cada função em um arquivo :\

Comment: Sua pergunta é bem interessante pra uma discussão, mas tenho uma dúvida sobre ela, porque você iria querer usar apenas uma função de um arquivo?

Comment: É porque eu não gosto de ter que criar um arquivo de funções sempre tendo que declarar as funções como no último exemplo... E também, cada função que é carregada, é mais memória (não sei se isso gera um consumo absurdo, mas de fato gera algum consumo ter funções declaradas, porém que eu não estou usando)

Comment: No php não é um problema grande ter, por exemplo, uma biblioteca com 200 funções, desde que cada uma delas esteja bem escrita. Isso não vai te trazer uma perda no desempenho do software grande o suficiente para fazer uma diferença notável ao usuário final. A forma que php e python funcionam são diferentes, então essa não é uma preocupação tão grande pra se ter no php.

Comment: Verifique se esse link lhe ajuda: [PHP import functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457653/php-import-functions)

Answer (score 3):

Não tem isso em PHP. Mas normalmente você não cria tantas funções soltas assim, normalmente você cria classes e elas contém funções/métodos, etc. E pra evitar conflito de nomenclaturas com as classes, existe um recurso chamado namespaces.

Comment: Amigo, o que seria "funções soltas"? Pois uma classe não é um repositório de funções. Já os namespaces resolvem os conflitos de nomes sim, porém quero carregar uma função de um arquivo que contém 25 funções declaradas?

Comment: Quis dizer que não é comum criar um arquivo com 25 funções que não tem nada em comum entre si. Por exemplo, se por acaso tiver 25 funções de operações matemáticas, crie um classe chamada Calculos e agrupe, algo do tipo. Não tem nada de errado nisso.
Mas isso que você quer de incluir apenas uma função de um arquivo com 25, infelizmente não existe isso em php =/

Comment: @WallaceMaxters para mim e pelo que leio o seu problema está na forma de abordar o assunto. Já pensou em classes. O caminho em PHP é OOP. Desenvolvo projectos de grande dimensão e um arquivo com tantas funções já não uso à anos.

Comment: entendo, @chambelix!. Eu só programo PHP com OOP também. Porém essa é uma curiosidade que surgiu.